# How to set ValidateInlineMaps in a Unit Test to test the Mapping of AutoMapper

Tags: unit-testing, automapper

I have the following test in which I want to test an AutoMapping while turning off ValidateInlineMaps, but the setting seems to have no effect. Am I doing it in the wrong way? Basically I am doing it like this:

'Mapper.Initialize(m => { m.ValidateInlineMaps = false;            m.AddProfile();  });'

I expected my test to pass 'AssertConfigurationIsValid' but it does not.

The full code of the test is:

```
using AutoMapper;
using Domain.Database.Entities;
using Shared.DTO.v000;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Domain.Bootstrap.Profiles;

namespace Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ProfileMappersTest
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
        }


        [Test]
        public void AutoMapper_Configuration_IsValid()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(m => { 
                m.ValidateInlineMaps = false;  
                m.AllowNullCollections = true; 
                m.AllowNullDestinationValues = true; 
                m.AddProfile<CustomerContactProfile>();  });
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            MapperConfiguration configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
              cfg.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDTO>());

            configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The static mapper is gone. Inline maps too. Maybe you should upgrade :)

Comment: I think I used the statement correctly though. I will confirm if I can proof it. I did something else wrong. This is the correct way of setting it.